# My " and ' keys started behaving strangely - multiple key presses needed for them to appear on screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

When I press the `"` or `'` keys (apostrophes), I need to press another key for the character  to appear on the screen.

If I press " twice in a row, there appear two "-s but only after second  key press.

If I press " once, nothing appears on the screen. As soon as I press a subsequent key, the " appears together with the subsequent key.

Same behavior with the ` key.

I initially thought this was a setting in Visual Studio I set somewhere by mistake - but now I noticed this is happening computer-wide in any application.

What is happening here? How do I set the keys back to their normal function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to your keyboard settings. Go to the keyboard settings and change the Keyboard from US international to US.

In case you cannot remove the US international keyboard, you must unmake it your default one and then remove it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I feel very dumb :) I have reinstalled the system 2 months ago and only now did I notice I chose the wrong keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

You have a keyboard layout with "dead keys" (probably US-International) enabled.
You can select the standard US keyboard layout in "Control Panel" under "Regional and Language".

Comment: Thank you, didn't expect the dead keys may apply to apostrophes on US international keyboard (despite the fact that I am used to these from my local keyboard which has accents)